# NGINX configuration for creating a shortlink service from existing shortlink web service

Tags: nginx, laravel-5.6, laravel-forge

I have an existing shortlink service with long domain name `longname.com/Wsdfsdf` . When the visitor clicks this link it redirects to `longname.com/order-details/customer-id/3435345345435`

Now I have a short domain name like `sh.rt` and would like every `longname.com/*` to behave same as `sh.rt/*`

As a result, when the visitor visits  `sh.rt/Wsdfsdf` it will redirect to `longname.com/order-details/customer-id/3435345345435` same as `longname.com/Wsdfsdf` would.

By doing this, I don't have to create a new server for `sh.rt`

I tried to add domain names in servername to NGINX config file but the problem could be `longname.com`  has default ssl and `sh.rt` doesn't have.

my Nginx file is:

```
include forge-conf/mydomain.com/before/*;


server {
      proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .mydomain.com;
    root /home/forge/mydomain.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/330472/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/330472/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '...';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/mydomain.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/mydomain.com/after/*;
```

Comment: Yes, with the content of longname.com/*. Since longname.com/* already redirects to  longername ( logname.com/orders/w324324 extended name ) . So it will behave exactly as longname shortlink behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want both sites to serve the same content:

```
server_name ~^longname.com|sh.rt$;
```

This is likely to result in problems with your SSL-Certificate though but you stated that you didn't want to use a separate server-block. If I were you I would configure this as an extra server-block with the same `root`-directory. Also this is more of a [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) question.

For additional documentation see:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: I will give a try and let you know. I created a serverfault question as well.
https://serverfault.com/questions/919047/nginx-configuration-for-creating-a-shortlink-service-from-existing-shortlink-web